# Criteria API Create new Object In Select Statement

Tags: java, jpa-2.0, jpql, criteria-api

I now that I can create new object in select statement with criteria api using code something like that

```
CriteriaBuilder cb...
CriteriaQuery<Wrapper> q = cb.createQuery(Wrapper.class);
  Root<SuperClass> c = q.from(SuperClass.class);
  q.select(cb.construct(Wrapper.class,c.get("name")));
```

But I was wondering if it's possible to create query like that using criteria api

```
select new Wrapper(p.name, type(p)) FROM SuperClass p
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if I understood your question correctly, but you can create something like that with HQL, at least with hibernate. You can see more [here](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html#queryhql-select).

It's like you showed. From Hibernate HQL Doc:

```
select new Family(mother, mate, offspr)
    from DomesticCat as mother
    join mother.mate as mate
    left join mother.kittens as offspr
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi Ralf, I must use Criteria Api, If I could use HQL or JPQL would not be a problem. The real problem is to extract information about entity class  (in JPQL I can use 'type' expression ) using Criteria API

Comment: @user1463860 I see. You could use `Transformers#aliasToBean` and use alias your properties to automatic transformation, our implement a `ResultTransformer` and do it manually.